# Using apply() in place of a for loop

Tags: r

So I have this for loop:

```
set.seed(11)
k=10000  # replicates
n=100    # sample size of each replication
t.mean = 0 # initialize vector of trimmed means 
for(i in 1:k){
  dat=rnorm(n)
  t.mean[i]=mean(dat,trim=.05)
}
mean(t.mean)
var(t.mean)
```

I am attempting to replace the code involved in the for loop with an apply() function instead

I figured this would work

```
set.seed = 11
k = 10000
n = 100
t.mean = 0
dat  = rnorm(n)
dat = as.data.frame(dat)
t.mean =apply(dat,c(1,2), mean,trim=.05)
mean(t.mean)
var(t.mean)
```

however, I do not get the same values as before and they do not stay the same either like in the previous case where a for loop is used. What exactly am I doing wrong when I am using apply?

Comment: This is failing because you call `rnorm(n)` *once*. You also don't want to use `c(1,2)` in the `apply()` call. Basically you aren't running this code `k` times, and the `c(1,2)` is basically applying `mean` to the 1st element of `dat[[1]]` then the 2nd element of `dat[[1]]` etc, which ends up returning the original values of `dat`.

Comment: ok I see, so you are saying It is only taking the mean of the first 2 values in dat? I tried changing it to 100 instead thinking it will take all the values, however it gives me an error: 

Error in if (d2 == 0L) { : missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed.

what exactly should I do here then to take the means of all value in dat?

Comment: how would I actually do rnorm(n) for every iteration without actually using a loop?

Comment: No, it is basically doing `mean(dat[[1]][1], trim = 0.05)` then `mean(dat[[1]][2], trim = 0.05)`, then `mean(dat[[1]][3], trim = 0.05)` etc, so it's just returning the original data.

Comment: `apply()` iterates over an array, so I don't think you can make it loop like you want, without creating the full set of random normal deviates. `sapply()`, `vapply()`, and `lapply()` would allow you to loop (`vapply(seq_len(k), function(x) mean(rnorm(100), trim = 0.05), numeric(1))` for example), but this is very similar to `replicate()`, and as i said in my answer, you can avoid calling `rnorm()` 10000 times if you follow the second example there.

Answer (score 2):

The `replicate()` function is potentially more useful here

```
set.seed(11)
out <- replicate(10, mean(rnorm(100), trim = 0.05))
```

which for `k <- 10` gives

```
> mean(out)
[1] 0.007134792
> var(out)
[1] 0.009029396
```

which matches with the `for` loop you showed for that same `k`.

Another alternative if you want to use `apply()` is to generate the *entire* set of random normal values, arrange them into a 100 row by `k` column matrix and then `apply()` `mean()` over the columns of that matrix. For example

```
set.seed(11)
rnd <- matrix(rnorm(100*k), ncol = k)
out2 <- apply(rnd, 2L, mean, trim = 0.05)
```

Gives the same as above as well as for your `for()` loop

```
> mean(out2)
[1] 0.007134792
> var(out2)
[1] 0.009029396
```

An advantage of this second route is that you call `rnorm()` once rather than `k` times.

Comment: Hey, so those are not the values I should get actually. the for loop gives me .0001381478 for the mean and .01026078 for the variance.

Comment: Did you change `k` to what I said: `k <- 10`? For that many replicates (10, not 10000) the answer are exactly the same --- I didn't feel like running a a loop 10000 times just to show the equivalence.